# how can i throttle routes with parameter for diffrent ips

Tags: laravel, throttling

i created a page visit function that works with laravel throttle. each ip/user can increase visit counter every 60 minutes.
i have a problem that can't apply throttle on different ids and throttle works on route only 1 time per 60 minutes and does'nt care about ids:
(/home/visit/3 , /home/visit/4 ,.....): 1 time every 60 mins

route.php:

```
Route::post('/home/visit/{id}',[HomeController::class,'counter_visit'])->middleware('throttle:visit');
```

RouteServiceProvider.php

```
            RateLimiter::for('visit', function (Request $request) {
            return $request->user()
                ? Limit::perHour(1)->by($request->user()->id)
                : Limit::perHour(1)->by($request->ip());
                });
```

how can i apply throttle for each id like below?

/home/visit/3 : 1 time every 60 mins
/home/visit/4 : 1 time every 60 mins

thanks for your helps

Comment: unfortunately Route::post('/home/visit/{id}',[HomeController::class,'counter_visit'])->middleware('throttle:1,60'); works same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the easiest way(maybe).
just create a custom middleware extending ThrottleRequests.

```
php artisan make:middleware ThrottleById
```

Http\middleware\ThrottleById.php.

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Middleware;
use Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests;
class ThrottleById extends ThrottleRequests
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure(\Illuminate\Http\Request): (\Illuminate\Http\Response|\Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse)  $next
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response|\Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse
     */
    protected function resolveRequestSignature($request)
    {
        $token = $request->route()->parameter('id'); 
        return $token;
    }
}
```

this function creates uique signature for each url if id parameter of route is different
then just add this middleware to kernel.php same as  part 3 & 4 in https://stackoverflow.com/a/75869783/9241751

thanks to [Balaji Kandasamy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/817365/balaji-kandasamy)

Answer (score 1):

Currently, you are using Laravel's built-in throttle middleware, which limits the number of requests for a given route per user or IP address, regardless of the ID parameter. To achieve throttling based on ID parameters, you need to define your own custom middleware.

Here's an example of how you can create a custom middleware that throttles requests based on ID:

1. Create a new middleware class by running the following command in your terminal:

**`php artisan make:middleware ThrottleById`**

2. Open the newly created ThrottleById middleware class and modify the handle() method to include the following code:

   use Illuminate\Cache\RateLimiter;

   use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

   use Illuminate\Http\Exceptions\ThrottleRequestsException;

   public function handle($request, Closure $next, $maxAttempts = 1, $decayMinutes = 60)

   {

   $limiter = app(RateLimiter::class)->for('visit_'.$request->route('id'), $maxAttempts, $decayMinutes);

   if ($limiter->tooManyAttempts($request)) {

   $retryAfter = $limiter->availableIn($request);

   throw new ThrottleRequestsException(null, $retryAfter, [

   'Retry-After' => $retryAfter,

   'X-RateLimit-Limit' => $maxAttempts,

   'X-RateLimit-Remaining' => 0,

   ]);

   }

   ```
    $limiter->hit($request);

    $response = $next($request);

    $response->headers->add([
        'X-RateLimit-Limit' => $maxAttempts,
        'X-RateLimit-Remaining' => $limiter->retriesLeft($request),
        'X-RateLimit-Reset' => $limiter->availableAt($request),
    ]);

    return $response;
   ```

   }

The above code is an implementation of Laravel's built-in throttle middleware, but modified to use the ID parameter of the request to create a unique cache key for each ID.

3. Next, register the middleware in the **$routeMiddleware** array in the **App\Http\Kernel** class:

   `protected $routeMiddleware = [ // ... 'throttle_by_id' => \App\Http\Middleware\ThrottleById::class, ];`
4. Finally, apply the new middleware to your route definition like this:

   `Route::post('/home/visit/{id}', [HomeController::class, 'counter_visit'])->middleware('throttle_by_id');`

Comment: unfortunately i get this error. i changed many things but dont get the correct result.
error in avilableAt and retriesLeft they need two arguments. i editted them but no result
Illuminate\Cache\RateLimiter::for(): Argument #2 ($callback) must be of type Closure, int given,

Comment: thanks a lot. i found another way to create unique ids for rourets id